# Nested Table Views giving UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a Swift Application that has a table view, where inside each cell is another sublist which we keep in a second table view. [image]

Each table view cell is composed of a Header area, another table view with sub items, and a footer area.

For some reason when you click right below the inner table view (highlighted in the image), it triggers an NSInvalidArgumentException with the following error and a long stack trace that isn't very helpful (I can provide it if someone thinks it will help).

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellAccessibilityElement superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7cd5f480'
```

I've set an exception breakpoint, but the debugger points to the AppDelegate on class initialization and provides no detailed info of where the error could be occurring.

I've experimented commenting out the code where I set the inner table view's delegate and datasource, and when I do so the error stops occurring, so I think that indicates that something is wrong with the inner table view.

The source code for the Custom Cells in question is located [here](https://github.com/Unome5548/nestedTableViews)

I'm assuming that the problem has something to do with accessibility, but I honestly have no idea what that even is, and have not been able to find related errors from my google searches. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off,

You should not have a table view inside of another table view. This can cause problems, as you have found. I suggest that you adjust your code to insert cells dynamically and have multiple cell types.

As for your accessibility error, I would try toggling the accessibility checkbox on the storyboard under the Identity Inspector.

If you have any other questions, please let me know.

Comment: That worked. I'm still confused as to why this was an error in the first place, but like you said maybe I should rethink how I'm doing this layout and avoid the nested table views.